# Abstract types in MXBean operation signatures

Tags: java, jmx, mxbean

I'm trying to create an MXBean operation which would return an abstract type w/o properties (the actual type and its attributes are to be determined at run time). My data model can be simply put as follows:

```
public interface I extends CompositeDataView {
    // empty
}

public final class A implements I {
    private final String foo;

    @ConstructorProperties({"foo"})
    public A(final String foo) {/* ... */}

    public String getFoo() {/* ... */}

    @Override
    public CompositeData toCompositeData(CompositeType ct) {/* ... */}

    public static A from(final CompositeData cd) {/* ... */}
}

public final class B implements I {
    private final String bar;

    @ConstructorProperties({"bar"})
    public B(final String bar) {/* ... */}

    public String getBar() {/* ... */}

    @Override
    public CompositeData toCompositeData(CompositeType ct) {/* ... */}

    public static B from(final CompositeData cd) {/* ... */}
}
```

... and the MXBean operation signature is:

```
@MXBean
public interface Baz {
    I f();
}
```

The operation can return either an instance of  `A` with a `foo` attribute, or an instance of `B` with a `bar` attribute.
Of course I'm presented with a shiny `NotCompliantMBeanException` immediately I try to register the `MBean` instance:

```
Caused by: javax.management.openmbean.OpenDataException: Can't map I to an open data type
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.makeCompositeMapping(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:458)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.makeMapping(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:292)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.mappingForType(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:257)
```

It seems there's something I can do with regular `MBean`s and `Serializable` but can't with `MXBean`s and `CompositeDataView`. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do more or less what you want, though not all that straightforward. The key point is that the MXBean spec requires a CompositeData to have at least one item. You can satisfy this requirement by having a property `type` in your base class, which I've called `AnyCompositeData` here. The `type` property can also serve to decide how to translate back from `CompositeData` to the specific types such as your `Foo` and `Bar`. In the code here I stuffed everything into the `AnyCompositeData` class, though more realistically it would be separate classes of course. I only spelled out the concrete class `Foo` but it should be obvious how to extend the pattern to support other classes.

```
public abstract class AnyCompositeData implements CompositeDataView {
  private final String type;

  public AnyCompositeData(String type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  public String getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public static AnyCompositeData from(CompositeData cd) {
    switch ((String) cd.get("type")) {
      case "Foo":
        return new Foo((String) cd.get("foo"));
      default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Don't know how to reconstruct: " + cd.get("type"));
    }
  }

  public static class Foo extends AnyCompositeData {
    private final String foo;

    Foo(String foo) {
      super("Foo");
      this.foo = foo;
    }

    public String getFoo() {
      return foo;
    }

    @Override
    public CompositeData toCompositeData(CompositeType ct) {
      try {
        String[] items = {"type", "foo"};
        OpenType<?>[] itemTypes = {SimpleType.STRING, SimpleType.STRING};
        Object[] itemValues = {"Foo", foo};
        CompositeType compositeType = new CompositeType("Foo", "Foo", items, items, itemTypes);
        return new CompositeDataSupport(compositeType, items, itemValues);
      } catch (OpenDataException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
  }

  @MXBean
  public interface Baz {
    AnyCompositeData f();
  }

  static class BazImpl implements Baz {
    @Override
    public AnyCompositeData f() {
      return new Foo("whatever");
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName("test:baz=baz");
    mbs.registerMBean(new BazImpl(), objectName);
    Baz bazProxy = JMX.newMXBeanProxy(mbs, objectName, Baz.class);
    AnyCompositeData result = bazProxy.f();
    assert result instanceof Foo;
    assert ((Foo) result).getFoo().equals("whatever");
  }
}
```

If you had a lot of subclasses like `Foo`, then you might want to consider using reflection in some way rather than having the `from(CompositeData)` method know about all the subclasses.

Comment: Thank you Eamonn!

I'd like to take this opportunity and thank you for your blog posts on JMX at https://www.java.net/blogs/emcmanus -- they're real great, I use them in my everyday work.